# How do i delete the first node of singly linked list chaining hash table if the next node in the same index is not NULL?

Tags: c, hashtable

this is my funtion, if i use this function to delete the first node it will delete all the rest of node->next node, anyone can help me?

```
struct node* popCH(char ex[]){
    int hash_index = Hash(ex);
    node* temp = head[hash_index];
    
    if(temp==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    
    while(temp->next!=NULL && strcmp(temp->next->ex,ex)!=0){
            temp=temp->next;
        }

    if(temp->next==NULL && strcmp(temp->ex,ex)==0){
        free(temp);
        temp=NULL;
        head[hash_index]=NULL;
    }
    
    else if(temp->next!=NULL && strcmp(temp->ex,ex)==0){
        node* temp2 = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        temp = head[hash_index]->next;
        free(temp2);
        temp2=NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a pointer to a pointer to a node so that the node can be deleted and the pointer to the node is updated to point at the next node regardless of the pointer is the head pointer of a pointer in a node.

```
struct data* popCH(char ex[]){
    int hash_index = Hash(ex);
    node** temp = &head[hash_index];
    
    if(*temp==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    
    while(*temp!=NULL && strcmp((*temp)->ex,ex)!=0){
        temp=&(*temp)->next;
    }

    if(*temp!=NULL){
        node *temp2 = (*temp)->next;
        free(*temp);
        *temp=temp2;
    }

    /* return something not to let caller invoke undefined behavior by using the return value */
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is with a pointer-to-pointer, which is already covered by an excellent answer.

Another one is simply to keep track of the pointer to the previous node, which is null when there is no previous node:

```
node *prev = NULL;

while (temp != NULL && strcmp(temp->ex, ex) != 0) {
   prev = temp;
   temp = temp->next;
}

if (temp != NULL) { // found matching node
   // retain data pointer to return before freeing
   struct data *data = temp->data;

   // two deletion cases: middle of chain or front
   if (prev)
     prev->next = temp->next;
   else
     head[hash_index] = temp->next;

   free(temp);
   return data;
}

// not found
return NULL;
```

We can avoid having two deletion cases if we give the chain a surrogate parent. That is to say, we add a dummy node to the front of the list which serves as the previous node for the first node:

```
struct data* popCH(const char *ex){
    int hash_index = Hash(ex);
    // transfer chain into fake extra previous node:
    struct node parent = { .next = head[hash_index] };
    node *prev = &parent;
    node *temp = prev->next;
    

    while (temp != NULL && strcmp(temp->ex, ex) != 0) {
       prev = temp;
       temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp != NULL) { // found matching node
       // retain data pointer to return before freeing
       struct data *data = temp->data;

       // splice temp out of list by getting
       // the previous node to skip it
       prev->next = temp->next;

       // transfer updated chain back into table:
       head[hash_index] = parent.next;

       free(temp);
       return data;
    }

    // not found
    return NULL;
}
```

We have eliminated some tests from the code, but there are some unnecessary memory writes. Before returning, we assign to `head[hash_index]` whether or not that is actually necessary; it is only necessary of `parent.next` has changed. Moreover, we have allocated an entire `node` local variable and initialized all of its fields, even though we only ever access `. We can avoid doing that by avoiding the initializer:

```
    int hash_index = Hash(ex);
    // transfer chain into fake extra previous node:
    struct node parent;
    node *prev = &parent;
    node *temp = head[hash_index];

    // initialize just parent.next member by assignment;
    // other members are left uninitialized.
    parent.next = temp;

    // rest of code ...
```

Comment: it shows me error message invalid use of 'data::data' in this line of code struct data *data = temp->data;

Comment: @Ollie That's because I'm guessing about your data structure. In your question, you defined the function such that it returns `struct data *`, yet you don't have a `return` statement anywhere. I took a guess that when we `popCH` the hash table, we should the return data in the successful case when the key is found and in the not-found case, we return `NULL`.  I then took the simplest possible guess about where the `data` is; you have to fix that yourself though to the actual situation.

Comment: `data::data`, by the way? Is this actually C++?